# Simple default operation with optional parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to create a method that takes two strings and gets called if I provide the params or not. It's proving to be difficult for me.

Here is my controller with the test method:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(string one, string two )
    {
        return "Testing";
    }
}
```

I would like the method to be available at the folloring urls:

- url/test/
- url/test/
- url/test/?one=1&two=2
- url/test/?one=1
- url/test/?two=2
- url/test/get
- url/test/get?one=1&two=2
- url/test/get?one=1
- url/test/get?two=2

I'm also planning to add POST support, but I think this will prove to much for WebAPI and I'll have to have a dedicated model class.

My routes are:

```
.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Basic", "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" });
```

I understand that I could set up routes to specify the 'one' and 'two' parameters, but my routes definitions sit in a central place and I'm not ready to pollute my global routes to cater for a special case in a controller (and then do it for hundred other methods).

It seems to me like a pretty basic scenario - what is the pattern to follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set default values on the parameters to make them optional:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get(string one = null, string two = null )
{
    return "Testing";
}
```